# Pygame script freezing on windows (Program not responding)

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to stackoverflow, I decided to join because I sometimes have problems with programming. This one is really annoying, I cant figure out why it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

I get the windows "Program not responding" error message

A simple display:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

BLUE = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)

size = [1280, 720] 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Hangman")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:

    # Leaves the fps at 30
    clock.tick(30)

    screen.fill(BLUE)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

The expected result is a blue screen, instead I get a blue screen that crashes

Comment: What is the expected result and what you get instead?

Comment: The expected result is a blue screen, instead I get a blue screen that crashes

Comment: Can you elaborate on "crashes"? Do you get an error message? If so, show us the exact, complete message.

Comment: "Program not responding" windows error message

Comment: Sorry, I did add the error message to the question, I must have accidentally copied the code over it.

Comment: Are you changing your done flag to `true` anywhere?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. That was a derp moment, forgot pygame.QUIT :)

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Can we please reopen this question. I have code that can fix killarviper's problem. I don't think this question was fairly closed either, as even though the error wasn't clearly defined, he did provide a minimal working example that *does* in fact, does freeze on start up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your game loop handling events will prevent freezing.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

BLUE = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)

size = [1280, 720] 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Hangman")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            sys.exit(0) 
        else: 
            print event
    # Leaves the fps at 30
    clock.tick(30)
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Just for further reference, this is referred to in the pygame docs (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html): "There are important things that must be dealt with internally in the event queue. The main window may need to be repainted or respond to the system. **If you fail to make a call to the event queue for too long, the system may decide your program has locked up.**"